# Div that takes up least width as possible with set height

Tags: html, css, dynamic, flexbox, width

I'm looking to create a div that only takes up as much width as it needs, with the height set to the height of the viewport. The problem I'm experiencing is that if the viewport height is reduced, the div's width doesn't update and the content overflows on the y-axis.

I've tried using flexbox to create two divs, one taking up the remaining room, but it doesn't force the other div to reduce in width so the words don't wrap.

Here's the first issue scenario:

[Flexbox content not wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EOqH.png)

In the image above, there are two div's using the following code:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.item-1 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:yellow;

}
.item-2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:red;
}
```

The issue is that the text isn't wrapping to reduce the width of the first box to as little as possible. Here would be the desired result:

[Desired flexbox content wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTL6M.png)

The second issue is that when the screen height is reduced, the content overflows instead of widening the div, as shown here:

[Code overflowing outside of div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3hXd.png)

Ideally, these are the two desired results I am looking for:

**Initial layout**

(no overflow and as little width as possible)

[Initial layout of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Itz.png)

**Modified layout**

(no overflow and the div width has widened to accommodate the content within it)

[Modified layout of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMC0n.png)

So far nothing I've tried has worked, am I asking for the impossible? I appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: I guess adding `flex-basis:0%` to the first div in your first code is only what is missing

Comment: Adding flex-basis:0% does solve one issue with the content taking up as little width as possible, but the content still overflows when the screen height is reduced.